# React Native network request failed

Tags: reactjs, ssl, react-native

How to skip ssl verification?

```
fetch('url',{ methhod: 'GET', header:{Accept:'application/json',}})
.then(res=>console.log(res))
```

[image: error log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sloved the problem with installing rn-fetch-blob library and bypass ssl certificate

```
   RNFetchBlob.config({ trusty: true })
  .fetch(
    'POST',
    'https://yourAPI',
    {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    dataObj
  )
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to make a GET request there is no need to pass the method and header info.

```
let apiUrl = "https://url/"
fetch(apiUrl)
 .then((response) => response.json())
 .then((jsonData=>{
   console.log(jsonData);
})
.catch((err)=>{
  console.log("err",err);
}
```